# Kicad PCBnew: Cannot figure out why DRC reports unconnected pads

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

I'm very new to KiCad and PCB design in general (this is my first project). I have just about finished up my first PCB and upon running the DRC realized that two of the pads in my schematic were being reported as unconnected. Here is a screenshot of the whole schematic (the red rectangle is where the two unconnected pads are):

[image]

Here is the circuit with the two 'unconnected'two highlighted with the red circles:
[image]

I have tried rerouting the PWR tracks in many different ways but the DRC always reports these pads as being unconnected. Hoping someone with more experience will be able to help!

Also if anyone notices any issues with my design please let me know! The board is essentially a 6-channel relay board with some extra bits that are project specific.

EDIT: Thought I should add in a screenshot of the DRC:
[image]

Comment: They are all connected through the ground plane.

Comment: Kicad does not consider them to be connected. Follow my advice in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It happened to me several times.
You have to draw new connection from the pad to the track. One of the pads is not connected to the track despite it's one over each other.